# Merge text into datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with 2 columns. 
`col1` is `date` and `col2` is `bigint`.
There are dummy values `1970-01-01 00:00:00` and `19700101000000`

```
col1                col2
2012-01-12 18:09:42 19700101000000
1970-01-01 00:00:00 20140701000001
```

I am looking for a way to merge these 2 columns into a single datetime column like this...

```
col3
2012-01-12 18:09:42
2014-07-01 00:00:01
```

Or is there any way to merge text from column col2 into col1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html), last add to `col1`:

```
print (pd.to_datetime(df.col2, format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
0   1970-01-01 00:00:00
1   2014-07-01 00:00:01
Name: col2, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print (pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime(df.col2, format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')))
0       0 days 00:00:00
1   16252 days 00:00:01
Name: col2, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

df.col1 = pd.to_datetime(df.col1)
df['col3'] = pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime(df.col2, format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')) + df.col1
print (df)
                 col1            col2                col3
0 2012-01-12 18:09:42  19700101000000 2012-01-12 18:09:42
1 1970-01-01 00:00:00  20140701000001 2014-07-01 00:00:01
```

Parameter `unit` can be used too:

```
df['col3'] = pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime(df.col2, format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S'), unit='ns') + 
             df.col1
print (df)
                 col1            col2                col3
0 2012-01-12 18:09:42  19700101000000 2012-01-12 18:09:42
1 1970-01-01 00:00:00  20140701000001 2014-07-01 00:00:01
```